# Given a C++ file with many function definitions, how to get the starting and ending index of a particular function using Python?

Tags: python, c++, parsing

The purpose is to comment the entire function `void test_func` with many nested `{}` using Python.

```py
file = open(path_of_file)
data = file.readlines()
for item in data:
    if item.find('void test_func') != -1:
        point = data.index(item)
        data.insert(point, '/*')
        stack = []
        for i in data[point+1:]:
            if i.find('{') != -1:
               stack.append('{')
            elif i.find('}') != -1:
               stack.pop()
            if len(stack) == 0:
               point1= data.index(i)
               data.insert(point1+1,'*/')
```

Using the `find()` method I can find the starting index of the function while iterating over the lines. I was trying to use the balanced parenthesis method, to reach the end of the function, So when my stack is empty I will reach the end of the `test_func`.

This is not working in this example:

```cpp
void test_func(arguments,\
arguments)
{
```

It is inserting `*/` just after the line:

```cpp
/*void test_func(arguments,\
*/arguments)
{
```

Comment: I very much doubt that this is possible reliably without using a complete C++ parser. How do you intent to for example tell function definitions apart from variable definitions with `{`/`}` initializer or from class definitions. How are you considering namespaces? What about braces in parameter types, etc.

Comment: Your example code example appears to be truncated.  It doesn't have the body of the "if len(stack) == 0:" statement.

Comment: Ino not using name spaces

Comment: The problem, though, would seem to be that you start looking for the open brace on the line after the "void test_func" line, but because of the line wrapped arguments there is no opening brace there, so len(stack) is zero and it prints the "*/".

Comment: @Malcolm data[point+1:] won't work? to start from next line

Comment: How about breaking the function after data.insert(point,'/*') and starting new for loop? but how do I make sure it starts from next line

Comment: You need to first make sure you have found the opening brace for the function, and then you can terminate when len(stack) == 0.

Comment: Note, that @user17732522 is correct.  To solve this problem in general would require having a full C++ parser.  For example, your code assumes that each line will contain only one opening brace or one closing brace.  That is not required by C++.  However, if you know the C++ file follows this convention you can get away with what you are doing.

Comment: There is also the question of whether your function might include its own "/*" type comments.  If so then wrapping the whole thing in "/*" comments won't do what you expect.  They don't get handled like parentheses, and nest.  Instead, the first "*/" after your inserted comment starts will terminate your commenting.  You will probably be better off using "//" line comments on each line until you get to the end of the function.

Comment: Can you please tell how to use c++ parser @ Malcolm
I am not aware.

Comment: (Sorry for the delay.)  You don't want to go down the full C++ parser route.  Unless you are trying to develop a general tool for distribution to others.  If you know your code abides by certain conventions, then you can make something much simpler.

Comment: Before making some other comments on the process, one thing I would say is that there is no need to generate point through a find(item).  Just use "for point, item in enumerate(data):"  That way you aren't doing the separate search through the data and you don't run into problems if you happen to have two identical lines in the file.

Comment: Next, I wouldn't create a separate parsing loop within a loop.  Just take the lines one at a time, and use state variables to identify where you are in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a "}\n" line only happens at the end of a function and always happens at the end of a function, you want something like:

```
in_func = False
for line in file.readlines():
    line = line.strip('\r\n') # remove line breaks since print will add them
    if in_func:
        print("// " + line)
        if line == "}":
            in_func = False
    elif line.startswith('void test_func('): # paren required to not match test_func2
        print("// " + line)
        in_func = True
    else:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both `(` / `)` pairs and `{` / `}` pairs are balanced, you can look for the `)` that balances the parameter list's `(` and then the `}` that balances the body's first `{`.

We want to ensure that `void test_func() {}` etc is also caught, so I've pulled out the checks into local functions, so we start looking on the same line for the next pair of characters.

```
file = open(path_of_file)
data = file.readlines()

start = None
params = None
body = None
open = 0
close = 0

for index, line in enumerate(data):

    def balanced(o, c):
        open += line.count(o)
        close += line.count(c)
        return open > 0 and open = close
    
    def checkBody():
        if balanced('{', '}'):
            body = index
    
    def checkParams():
        if balanced('(', ')'):
            params = index
            open = 0
            close = 0
            checkBody()
    
    def checkStart():
        if line.find('void test_func') != -1:
            start = index
            checkParams()

    if start is None:
        checkStart()
    elif params is None:
        checkParams()
    elif body is None:
        checkBody()

if start is not None and body is not None:
    data.insert(start, '/*')
    data.insert(body + 1, '*/')
```